# Specific mailing always fails with 42% success rate

Tags: civimail

I have a mailing group, which isn't a smart group, that always fails at 42%. I then add the successful ones to a group and resend the mailing and exclude that group. This then sends 32%. I repeat the above and the mailing is successful. This is the only mailing group on this site that is causing the problem and they send a lot of emails.

I check the logs and get this error:

```
"$Fatal Error Details = Array ( 
  [callback] => Array ( 
     [0] => CRM_Core_Error 
     [1] => exceptionHandler ) 
  [code] => -2 
  [message] => DB Error: syntax error 
  [mode] => 16 
  [debug_info] => SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name` FROM civicrm_mailing a 
    WHERE (a.name LIKE "%success%") 
    ORDER BY a.is_archived, a.scheduled_date DESC 
    LIMIT 11 
    OFFSET -10 
  [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-10' at line 6] 
  [type] => DB_Error 
  [user_info] => SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name` 
    FROM civicrm_mailing a 
    WHERE (a.name LIKE "%success%") 
    ORDER BY a.is_archived, a.scheduled_date DESC 
    LIMIT 11 
    OFFSET -10 
  [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-10' at line 6] 
  [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name` FROM civicrm_mailing a WHERE (a.name LIKE "%success%") ORDER BY a.is_archived, a.scheduled_date DESC LIMIT 11 OFFSET -10 [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-10' at line 6]"] 
)"
```

I then get a lot of errors around blank email body so skipping emails.

```
CiviMail will not send an empty mail body, Skipping:
```

I have created a new group, added people to it and retested it with the same results.

Nothing obvious that I can see is causing the problem so I am at a loss to resolve it.

Cheers
Bari

Backtrace:

```
  `$backTrace = 
  #0 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(915): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) 
  #1 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error)) 
  #2 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(998): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: syntax error", -2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`\nFROM civicrm_mailing a\nWHERE (a.name ...") 
  #3 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`\nFROM civicrm_mailing a\nWHERE (a.name ...") 
  #4 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`\nFROM civicrm_mailing a\nWHERE (a.name ...", "DB_Error", TRUE) 
  #5 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1925): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7)) 
  #6 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(935): DB_common->raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`\nFROM civicrm_mailing a\nWHERE (a.name ...", "1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspon...") 
  #7 /home/Sitepublic_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(405): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError() 
  #8 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1231): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`\nFROM civicrm_mailing a\nWHERE (a.name ...") 
  #9 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2696): DB_common->query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`\nFROM civicrm_mailing a\nWHERE (a.name ...") 
  #10 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1829): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`\nFROM civicrm_mailing a\nWHERE (a.name ...") 
  #11 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(421): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`\nFROM civicrm_mailing a\nWHERE (a.name ...") 
  #12 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1408): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`\nFROM civicrm_mailing a\nWHERE (a.name ...", TRUE) 
  #13 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/SelectQuery.php(127): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`\nFROM civicrm_mailing a\nWHERE (a.name ...") 
  #14 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/utils.php(1260): Civi\API\SelectQuery->run() 
  #15 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Mailing.php(238): _civicrm_api3_basic_get("CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing", (Array:8), TRUE, "Mailing") 
  #16 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_mailing_get((Array:8)) 
  #17 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(150): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:8)) 
  #18 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(81): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:8)) 
  #19 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(131): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("mailing", "get", (Array:8)) 
  #20 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Generic/Getlist.php(39): civicrm_api3("mailing", "get", (Array:8)) 
  #21 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(85): civicrm_api3_generic_getList((Array:8)) 
  #22 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(150): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:8)) 
  #23 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(81): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:8)) 
  #24 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(22): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Mailing", "getlist", (Array:6)) 
  #25 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php(300): civicrm_api("Mailing", "getlist", (Array:6)) 
  #26 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php(550): CRM_Utils_REST::process((Array:3), (Array:6)) 
  #27 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(277): CRM_Utils_REST::ajax() 
  #28 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12)) 
  #29 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3)) 
  #30 /home/Site/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(456): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3)) 
  #31 /home/Site/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("ajax", "rest") 
  #32 /home/Site/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() 
  #33 {main}"`
```

Comment: So it doesn't like "OFFSET -10".  Do the logs also show the backtrace of the code resulting in the error?

Comment: Added backtrace, not very good formatting, I need to learn this!

Comment: Just throw in some line breaks and spaces at the start of lines ::-)

Answer (score 3):

Resolved this by creating a new email template, it seems as if something in the template was causing the problem.

No idea what, but this was the way we fixed the issue.